# Chrome não mostra conexão segura no celular

Tags: htaccess, segurança, google-chrome, ssl, https

Olá, estou com um problema chato com o protocolo HTTPS, mas acontece apenas quando acesso pelo celular. Quando acesso pelo desktop, meu site mostra o cadeado corretamente e a conexão HTTPS, mas quando acesso pelo celular, ele mostra como conexão insegura, como se não houvesse o certificado SSL.

Estou usando o código .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

# https
# utilizar esta regra apenas no site que estiver no ar
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off



# https
# utilizar esta regra apenas no site que estiver no ar
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]



# funciona sem digitar .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1\.php
```

Lembrando que o problema ocorre apenas quando acessado pelo celular.
Qualquer ajuda será bem vinda =)
Fiz uns testes e no Firefoz funcionou legal, mostrando conexão segura. O problema é apenas no Google Chrome e no celular, e isso já aconteceu outras vezes.

O site: https://inovatech.inf.br/

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -2):

Seu site já possui o certificado de `SSL`? Se sim, é porque seu `.htaccess` está com algum problema, pois ele não está redirecionando seu `HTTP` para `HTTPS`. Adicione o seguinte código à ele:

**Redirecionar HTTP para HTTPS:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Fonte: [How to force SSL](https://www.siteground.com/kb/how-to-force-ssl-with-htaccess/?gclid=Cj0KCQiA3rKQBhCNARIsACUEW_bTbLGZmNNPg0zCLehdKk9ABungyXS-BRVmp05SepSan-mDWu5jCDcaAo76EALw_wcB).

Comment: Sim, meu site já possui SSL habilitado e o redirecionamento de http para https ocorre normalmente quando acessado no desktop, o problema é quando acesso do celular, que é como se não tivesse certificado